# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined at delete_student

Tags: javascript

[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1K8d.png) 
this is image error of the page
This is `validation.js`

```
 function delete_student(st_id){
            if(confirm("Do you want to delete the student?")){
                this.document.student_view.st_id.value = st_id;
                this.document.student_view.st_act.value= "delete_student";
                this.document.student_view.submit();
            }
        }
```

This is `student.php`

```
function delete_student(){
    $SQL = "DELETE FROM student WHERE st_id = $_REQUEST[st_id]";
    $rs= mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());
    if($rs)
    {
        header("Location:../student_view.php?msg=Student Deleted  succesfully");
    }
}
?>
```

This is `student_view.php`

```
<?php 
while($data= mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
?>
<tr>
    <td><?=$data['st_id']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['st_name']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['st_father']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['st_mobile']?></td>
    <td>Edit | <a href="Javascript:delete_student(<?=$data['st_id'] ?>)">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>

</table>
<input type="hidden" name="act" />
<input type="hidden" name="st_id"> 
</form>
<?php include_once("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

When I check the console I’m geting the error as below.

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined at delete_student
> ```

When I check the console I’m geting the error as below.

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined at delete_student
> ```

Comment: cannot tell what's the error any more than console did from the code

Comment: The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** tab. You can also right-click and “Inspect Element” on your table. The PHP code is useless for us. You should debug with your _rendered_ HTML output.

Comment: @Xufox i have edited the code check it

Comment: @Xufox the actual problem is that when i try to delete the particular id from the table it is not getting deleted

Comment: Did you mean `act` instead of `st_act`?

Comment: @Xufox leave act aside ....the problem is with st_id .....it is not deleting the st_id

Comment: @Xufox i have a  error page in the form  image